# Доступ к mySQL на сервере Ubuntu только с одного внешнего IP

Tags: mysql

Как правильно ограничить доступ к mySQL на сервере Ubuntu, разрешая подключаться лишь для одного/двух внешних IP-адресов?

На сервере несколько баз данных. Подключаюсь к ним удаленно с помощью HeidiSQL указывая IP-сервера, пользователя и пароля (для каждой базы свои).

В логах /var/lib/mysql/error.log вижу, что ежесекундно пытаются подключиться удаленно перебирая имя пользователя и пароли. Логи разрастаются быстро. fail2ban работает, но хотелось бы сразу на уровне IP блокировать подключения.

Поискал решения, но предлагают создать пользователя и дать ему привилегии. Но баз данных то несколько. Для каждой базы создавать привилегии?

Comment: 1) Ограничьте доступ к сервису средствами ОС (если входящий пакет идёт на порт MySQL, но не от разрешённого адреса - drop). Тем же iptables или что там у Вас... 2) Ограничьте доступ к данным - для каждой БД или группы БД создайте роль с нужными правами доступа, каждого пользователя (с определённой хост-частью полного имени, а не с `@'%'`) наделите только нужными ролями.